# WFS-T returns 'Success' but doesn't delete feature

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I have a layer on my local GeoServer. I have published it, now I can successfully access it with WFS operations (DescribeFeatureType, GetFeature etc.). I have also enabled the transactions on WFS and give the necessary write permission to all the roles (including the anonymous roles). I am trying to delete a feature from my layer by using WFS-T.

Here is my URL (**Aydin1** is the workspace name):
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Aydin1/ows

Here is my WFS-T XML which I use in my POST request:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <wfs:Transaction 
   service="WFS" 
   version="1.0.0"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
   <wfs:Delete typeName="Aydin1:PointLayer">
        <Filter>
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ValueReference>details</ValueReference>
                <Literal>DetailsPoint1</Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </Filter>
   </wfs:Delete>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

And here is the answer I get from the server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:WFS_TransactionResponse version="1.0.0"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">
    <wfs:InsertResult>
        <ogc:FeatureId fid="none"/>
    </wfs:InsertResult>
    <wfs:TransactionResult>
        <wfs:Status>
            <wfs:SUCCESS/>
        </wfs:Status>
    </wfs:TransactionResult>
</wfs:WFS_TransactionResponse>
```

So, as you see, my transaction is successful, I don't get any error message. However, when I check my layer on GeoServer, I still see my feature, it hasn't been deleted. I know that my **Filter** structure is just fine; the exact filter is working well when I use **GetFeature** WFS operation.

I have published two different layers. One of them is based on shapefiles, the other one comes from PostGIS. They act the same way, that is, I get the **SUCCESS** response message but nothing happens.

What could be the problem?

Comment: the fact you get an **InsertResult** is suspicious - turn logging up and check what is really going on - my guess is that you are mixing FES2.0 filters with a WFS 1.0.0 request may confuse things.